# Radio buttons binding doesn't work in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

They simply do not work.

https://jsfiddle.net/23yf1mqu/1/

```
<div id="app">
  <p>
  Foo is: {{foo}} <a href="#" v-on:click="click">increment</a>
  </p>

  <div class="row mb-4">
                    <div class="col col-6">foo</div>
                    <div class="col col-6">
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <label class="btn btn-light">
                                <input type="radio" name="bar" id="bar_0" value="0" v:model="bar"> None
                            </label>
                            <label class="btn btn-light">
                                <input type="radio" name="bar" id="bar_1" value="1" v:model="bar"> Direct
                            </label>
                            <label class="btn btn-light">
                                <input type="radio" name="bar" id="bar_2" value="2" v:model="bar"> Inherit
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    foo: 1
  },
  methods: {
    click: function()
    {
        this.foo = this.foo === 2 ? 0 : this.foo + 1;
    }
  }
})
```

Using `v-bind:value` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` is a directive with this syntax `v-model="someData"`, you should replace `:` by hyphen `-` :

```
  <input type="radio" name="bar" id="bar_0" value="0" v-model="bar">
```

and add that `bar` property to the data object as follows :

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
  return {
    foo: 1,
   bar:1
  } 
 },
  methods: {
    click: function()
    {
        this.foo = this.foo === 2 ? 0 : this.foo + 1;
    }
  }
})
```